# Azure Pipeline Enable Task base on variable value

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a task in my pipeline which should be enabled base on the value of a variabe. The variable is defined in a separate yml file and it is set to true or false.

```
          - task: AzurePowerShell@3
            displayName: 'Create envionment'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'id'
              ScriptPath: $(workFolder)/Provisions/Environment/create.ps1
              errorActionPreference: stop
              azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
             enabled: $(createEnvironment)
```

However this gives me an error :
`Unexpected value $(createEnvironment)`

Is it not possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `${{variables.createEnvironment}}` to refer to the variable. See below:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@3
  displayName: 'Create envionment'
  inputs:
    ....   
  enabled: ${{variables.createEnvironment}}
```

The reason `$(createEnvironment)` not working is because `$()` is parsed at runtime. But `${{}}` will be parsed at compile time. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax) for more information.

You can also use **Condition**. But you need to wrap the variable `createEnvironment` in single quote `''`.See below:

```
condition: eq(variables['createEnvironment'], true)
```

Comment: I ended up using the `condition` and it works with the  quotes. Thanks !

Comment: Conditions override the default behaviour of skipping when a user cancels or a previous step is not successful. To include these checks, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using condition vs enabled parameter. It should look like this:

```
          - task: AzurePowerShell@3
            displayName: 'Create envionment'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'id'
              ScriptPath: $(workFolder)/Provisions/Environment/create.ps1
              errorActionPreference: stop
              azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
             condition: eq(variables[createEnvironment], true)
```

Comment: When I try that, I get the error `Unrecognized value: 'createEnvironment'. Located at position 14 within expression: eq(variables[createEnvironment], true).`   Usually this variable is referenced in my pipeline using the syntax `$(createEnvironment)`. I tried that too but it does not work either. Is this supposed to work with user-defined variables ?

Comment: @Sam - conditional insertion works with user defined variables see here: [ADO Pipeline - Conditions] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: I have seen this documentation but there is no example of a condition using user defined variable in a separate yaml file. They use either pipeline variable or parameters, which both work indeed. But if I use a variable $(myvar) defined in a variable yaml file, it is not recognized (although I can echo the value of the variable so the problem is related to the condition)